# Asp.Net Core Mvc using identity With N-Tier Architecture

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, identity, n-tier-architecture, asp.net-core-identity

I just built a web application with n-tier architecture and i want to use Identity for (Login in and register) user.

My blank solution contains :

1. UI (Presentation Layer)
2. DAL (Data Access Layer)
3. BL (Business Layer)
4. DTO (Data Transfer Object (Which contains models to use it on -(UI)- Layer))
5. Common Layer (using Infrastructure etc...)

My question is how can i use Identity with those tiers...

Comment: If this is an ASP.NET Core MVC project then you'd implement it in the middleware and controller.  But I'd say just use one of the project templates that include identity.

Comment: Should I need to make another DBContext on Presentation Layer for (IdentityDbContext)?

Comment: This is a bit all hand-wavy (the way the question is being asked) but typically the context bit would go into the DAL.

Comment: I think this is just another option-based question. If you think you will have different implementations for identity, then now you should create just generic interfaces, and have the ASP.NET Core Identity as one of the identity implementations. I would put it as a class project under Common Layer. If you think you will stick with ASP.NET Core Identity, just like you will stick with EntityFrameworkCore, then you can put everything within your UI layer.